# custom json encoders in python/tornado

Tags: python, json, tornado, cyclone

I'm building in tornado (cyclone, actually), and RequestHandler.write is choking on some of my objects.  How do I write a JSONencoder for these objects in tornado?

One complication: some of the objects are borrowed from external libraries, so I don't really have access to their constructors.

Apologies for not posting code -- I'm just not sure how to begin here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the answer is that tornado doesn't support custom json formatting, so you have to use the json library.  Here's the code I used in the end:

```
import json

class MongoEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

print json.dumps(my_mong_obj, cls=MongoEncoder, indent=2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to hook it up to be the default output for every handler in my application?

Comment: @tutuca define it in one python class and import from that python class instead of `import json`. You also may try setting it within the handler object through inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can change the default encoder, by adding this befor your mainloop

```
import json
json._default_encoder = YourJSONEncoder() #patch json
```

Answer (score 1):

For datetime object with json formatting it would looks like this

```
    import json

    dthandler = lambda obj: obj.isoformat() if isinstance(obj, datetime) else None
    response = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, default=dthandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my monkey patch:

```python
import json, datetime
from tornado import escape
DT_HANDLER = lambda obj: obj.isoformat() if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime) or     isinstance(obj, datetime.date) else None
def json_encode(value):
    return json.dumps(value, default=DT_HANDLER).replace("</", "<\/")

escape.json_encode = json_encode
```